# How to extract from associative array based on criteria in another array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects which contain data like this:

```
const RoomsDetails = [
    {
        "RoomId" : "37A",
        "NumberOfBeds" : "4"
    },
    {
       "RoomId" : "38A",
       "NumberOfBeds" : "5"
    },
    {   
        "RoomId" : "39A",
        "NumberOfBeds" : "4"
    }
]
```

and other array which contains active Room Ids:

```
const ActiveRoomsIds = ["37A", "39A"]
```

Now I want to extract only those rooms from `RoomsDetails` whose *RoomId's* are present in `ActiveRoomsIds`.

I need some help on how to do this via short code

Comment: Associative Arrays in JavaScript are called Objects.

Comment: Your first code looks like an array of objects. It’s helpful to write code samples in valid javascript so there’s no ambiguity ( and so people trying to help don’t have to retype or fix it).

Comment: why not write it as an object that would help understand what you're doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get only the active rooms based on ActiveRoomsIds array, you could use filter as such:

```
RoomsDetails.filter( f => ActiveRoomsIds.indexOf(f.RoomId) > -1);
```

Comment: should i put this in the variable like Active = oomsDetails.filter( f => ActiveRoomsIds.indexOf(f.RoomId) > -1);'

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like :

```
const results = RoomDetails
  .map( (room) => room.RoomId ) // get the roomId
  .filter(roomId => ActiveRoomsIds.indexOf(roomId) !== -1); //exists in array of rooms
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Beaten by less than one minute :). Is there any benefit of using the map in this case?

Comment: Congratulations ! :) Not really just for the sake of clarity !

Comment: Doesn't really make sense to do that mapping. End result would be array with exact same values as `ActiveRoomsIds` perhaps in different order

Answer (score 1):

You can do it also using [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const RoomsDetails = [
    {
        "RoomId" : "37A",
        "NumberOfBeds" : "4"
    },
    {
       "RoomId" : "38A",
       "NumberOfBeds" : "5"
    },
    {   
        "RoomId" : "39A",
        "NumberOfBeds" : "4"
    }
]

const ActiveRoomsIds = ["37A", "39A"]

const Active = RoomsDetails.filter( room => ActiveRoomsIds.includes(room.RoomId) )

console.log(Active);
```

**EDIT:**

If you only want to return the `RoomId` property (without `NumberOfBeds`) in the array of objects, you can do it like this:

```
RoomsDetails
.filter( room => ActiveRoomsIds.includes(room.RoomId) )
.map(room => ({RoomId: room.RoomId}) )
// [ { RoomId: '37A' }, { RoomId: '39A' } ]
```